# Rails console in Netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

Netbeans ide has rails console? I use Netbeans for PHP for a long time, and now I want use to my Rails applications. I saw the generators, bundle has a fast gui menu, but can I use this commands myself in Netbeans, so I looking a built in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right-click on the project in ur Project window, u will see a selection called "Rails Console"

-edit-

if you want shell, terminal. you might have to launch it will `cmd`, `ssh` or whatever way to access it.

--edit 2--
you might can check this out:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRubyTerminalEmulator

Comment: if I type rails generate controller Page index home, i get error NameError: undefined local variable or method `generate' for main:Object

Comment: ohh, what u need is a shell console, not rails console (or terminal console), I dunno think it exists in netbeans.